# Am trying to update data on vb.net with access database but the data does not update and there is no error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have declared sql, cmd and cnt on public class, and also i have declare my database on Module.

```
Dim sql As String 
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim cnt As Long

   Try

      sql = "UPDATE  [LDF]  SET [Group_Code] = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "',  
                                [Loan_Disb] ='" & TextBox1.Text & "',
                          [No_Of_Instalment] = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "',
                          [Single_Instalment]='" & TextBox2.Text & "',
                          [Loan_Security]='" & TextBox3.Text & "',
                          [Total_Amnt_TR]='" & TextBox4.Text & "', 
                          [Member_Name]='" & TextBox5.Text & "',
                          [Group_Name]='" & TextBox6.Text & "',
                          [Date_Of_Disb]='" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' 
                          WHERE [Member_Number] = ' & ComboBox3.Text & '"

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Con)
        cnt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox("RECORD HAVE SUCCESSFUL UPDATED")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: Dont concat strings for SQL, use SQL Parameters.  Some of those things are clearly numbers but you are passing text.  If that is the actual code, you are missing a quote mark and passing some form of a literal `ComboBox3.Text` via the WHERE clause.  Parameters will prevent that too,

Comment: Thanks, so what should use for sql and what is supposed to used on WHERE clause? @Plutonix

Comment: The WHERE clause is just another parameter, the 10th in this case

Comment: Everything you pass to this SQL via string manipulation should be a parameter instead. This ensures proper datatype checking and prevents SQL injection attack.

Comment: Thanks for your comments,@Plutonix and ManoDestra, Am new in Programming, so can you please tell me what i can write or if possible can you please give me the reference so that i can read myself. Please!!!!!

Comment: Please!! I Real need your guys.